# Sequelize EagerLoadingError: Users is not associated to UserGroups

Tags: sequelize.js, many-to-many

I’m trying to query my UserGroups model and include the associated Users model using Sequelize. However, I keep getting the error EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Users is not associated to UserGroups!. I have defined the associations between my models as follows:

```
Users.belongsToMany(Groups, { through: UserGroups, foreignKey: "userId" });
Groups.belongsToMany(Users, { through: UserGroups, foreignKey: "groupId" });
```

And here is the code for my getGroupDetail function where I’m trying to query the UserGroups model and include the Users model:

```
const getGroupDetail = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("hi");
  const { groupId, groupName } = req.query;
  const members = await UserGroupM.findAll({
    where: { groupId: groupId },
    include: Users,
  });
  console.log(members);
  res.json(members);
};
```

I have checked that the file where I define the associations is being imported and executed before I run this function. However, I’m still getting the error. Can anyone help me figure out what might be causing this issue?

```
const getGroupDetail = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("hi");
  const { groupId, groupName } = req.query;
  console.log(Users.associations);
  console.log(UserGroups.associations);
  const members = await UserGroupM.findAll({
    where: { groupId: groupId },
    include: Users,
  });
  console.log(members);
  res.json(members);
};
```

this is also showing `{ Messages: Messages, Groups: Groups } {}` meaning that there is no association with the UserGroupM for anything. I have imported things correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to query the junction table model as a main model and include associated models then you need to define reverse associations from the junction table model to two main table models:

```js
UserGroups.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: 'userId'});
UserGroups.belongsTo(Groups, { foreignKey: 'groupId'});
```